# Why when I do redirect in Web API it sends EXPIRES HEADER with value -1 in the response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I think this is not the correct behavior, based on the [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

> The format is an absolute date and time as defined by HTTP-date in section 3.3.1; it MUST be in RFC 1123 date format:
>
> Expires = "Expires" ":" HTTP-date
> An example of its use is
>
> Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
> Note: if a response includes a Cache-Control field with the max-
> age directive (see section 14.9.3), that directive overrides the
> Expires field.

For example:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return this.Redirect("http://localhost:60650/");
    }

}
```

Then, I do call via Fiddler:

[image]

Then, I have two responses, the first one is the redirect (HTTP 302):

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Pragma: no-cache
> Expires: -1
> Location: localhost:60650
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
> X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcaWdvci5jYW1wb3NcZG9jdW1lbnRzXHZpc3VhbCBzdHVkaW8gMjAxNVxQcm9qZWN0c1xSZWRpcmVjdFRlc3RcUmVkaXJlY3RUZXN0XGFwaVx2YWx1ZXM=?=
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> Date: Mon, 09 May 2016 20:35:37 GMT
> Content-Length: 0

Why ASP.NET sends the "Expires" HEADER with value -1 in this redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From section 14.21 of the RFC you linked:

> HTTP/1.1 clients and caches MUST treat other invalid date formats,
>   especially including the value "0", as in the past (i.e., "already
>   expired").

In other words, don't cache the fact that hitting this URL results in a redirect.

If you want it cached (and a permanent redirect result to the browser), use:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return this.RedirectPermanent("http://localhost:60650/");
}
```

Comment: In this case, the "HTTP/1.1 clients and caches" will be those who are consuming this API? For example a browser or another system?

Comment: @IgorCampos Yes, it includes browser, app, and search crawlers. It also includes proxy and caching servers, which aren't technically the end consumers of the API, but the RFC still mandates that they are not to cache the results either.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to want a temporary redirect cached when you know and control the interval by which the redirection url is changing. But one cannot change a permenent redirect from server side, so beware of using `RedirectPermanent()`.